# fetch data from a variables memory address one byte at a time

Tags: c

I have a small bit of code that attempts to demonstrate the various standard integer
types and to show that memory seems to get allocated in the stack with the largest 
datatypes first. What I wrote seems reasonable up until the last line where I get way
too many bytes of output. I really just wanted ( and expected ) to get just one byte.

Thus :

```
#include <stdint.h>  /* defines the standard integer types */
#include <stdio.h>   /* defines all the IO functions */
#include <stddef.h>  /* standard definitions */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* standard library functions */

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    int8_t  little_i = 11;
    int16_t med_i = 12062;
    int32_t norm_i = 1991;
    int64_t big_i = -3245321806; 

    /* these next items are pointers */
    int8_t *little_p; 

    printf ( "here is a little  8-bit int : little_i = %02x\n", little_i );
    printf ( "here is a medium 16-bit int : med_i    = %04x\n", med_i );
    printf ( "here is a normal 32-bit int : norm_i   = %08x\n", norm_i );
    printf ( "here is a big    64-bit int : big_i    = %016lx\n", big_i );

    printf ( "addr of little_i is %p" , &little_i );  
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(little_i) );
    printf ( "addr of med_i    is %p" , &med_i );  
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(med_i) );
    printf ( "addr of norm_i   is %p" , &norm_i );   
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(norm_i) );
    printf ( "addr of big_i    is %p" , &big_i );   
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(big_i) );

    /* tell us about the pointer */
    printf ( "\n--------------------------------------------------\n" );
    printf ( " size of the pointer little_p is %d\n" , sizeof(little_p) );
    printf ( " the address of the pointer itself is %p\n", &little_p );

    little_p = &little_i;

    printf ( "\nthe pointer little_p now contains the addr %p\n", little_p );
    printf ( "The data there, in memory, at the addr %p is 0x%02xh\n",
                         little_p, *little_p );

    /* we can point a pointer anywhere we want */
    little_p = (void *) &big_i;

    printf ( "\n\nthe pointer little_p now has the addr %p\n", little_p );

    printf ( "The data there, in memory, at the addr is 0x%02xh\n",
                                                    *( (int8_t*) little_p) );

    return ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

The output I get looks great up until the last line :

```
$ ./dtypes
here is a little  8-bit int : little_i = 0b
here is a medium 16-bit int : med_i    = 2f1e
here is a normal 32-bit int : norm_i   = 000007c7
here is a big    64-bit int : big_i    = ffffffff3e9051b2
addr of little_i is ffffffff7ffff56b and the size is 1
addr of med_i    is ffffffff7ffff568 and the size is 2
addr of norm_i   is ffffffff7ffff564 and the size is 4
addr of big_i    is ffffffff7ffff558 and the size is 8

--------------------------------------------------
 size of the pointer little_p is 8
 the address of the pointer itself is ffffffff7ffff550

the pointer little_p now contains the addr ffffffff7ffff56b
The data there, in memory, at the addr ffffffff7ffff56b is 0x0bh


the pointer little_p now has the addr ffffffff7ffff558
The data there, in memory, at the addr is 0xffffffffh
```

I expected to see just one byte 0xffh on that last line but got a full 32 bit integer size result. I thought the cast of little_p to an pointer of type int8_t* would do the trick.

Did I miss something obvious ?

----- update just AFTER I post this question :

I changed the last line there to a cast to uint8_t* :

```
    printf ( "The data there, in memory, at the addr is 0x%02xh\n",
                                                *( (uint8_t*) little_p) );
```

Which gives me the output :

```
The data there, in memory, at the addr is 0xffh
```

Mostly because bytes in memory would be unsigned 8-bits at a time.

Seems reasonable.

----------- further edit to extract and print the bytes from the 64-bit integer ------

Here is an updated code chunk :

```
$ cat dtypes.c
#include <stdint.h>  /* defines the standard integer types */
#include <stdio.h>   /* defines all the IO functions */
#include <stddef.h>  /* standard definitions */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* standard library functions */

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    int8_t  little_i = 11;
    int16_t med_i = 12062;
    int32_t norm_i = 1991;
    int64_t big_i = -3245321806; 

    void *little_p; /* void datatype is no datatype at all really. */

    printf ( "here is a little  8-bit int : little_i = %02x\n", little_i );
    printf ( "here is a medium 16-bit int : med_i    = %04x\n", med_i );
    printf ( "here is a normal 32-bit int : norm_i   = %08x\n", norm_i );
    printf ( "here is a big    64-bit int : big_i    = %016lx\n", big_i );

    printf ( "addr of little_i is %p" , &little_i );  
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(little_i) );
    printf ( "addr of med_i    is %p" , &med_i );  
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(med_i) );
    printf ( "addr of norm_i   is %p" , &norm_i );   
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(norm_i) );
    printf ( "addr of big_i    is %p" , &big_i );   
    printf ( " and the size is %d\n" , sizeof(big_i) );

    /* tell us about the pointer */
    printf ( "\n--------------------------------------------------\n" );
    printf ( " size of the pointer little_p is %d\n" , sizeof(little_p) );
    printf ( " the address of the pointer itself is %p\n", &little_p );

    /* we can point a pointer anywhere we want */
    little_p = (void *) &big_i;

    printf ( "\n\nthe pointer little_p now has the addr %p\n", little_p );

    printf ( "The data there, in memory, at the addr is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p) );

    printf ( "                             at addr+1 is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p+1 ) );

    printf ( "                             at addr+2 is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p+2 ) );

    printf ( "                             at addr+3 is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p+3 ) );

    printf ( "                             at addr+4 is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p+4 ) );

    printf ( "                             at addr+5 is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p+5 ) );

    printf ( "                             at addr+6 is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p+6 ) );

    printf ( "                             at addr+7 is 0x%02xh\n",
                                               *( (uint8_t*) little_p+7 ) );

    return ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

This gives the very nice results :

```
$ ./dtypes
here is a little  8-bit int : little_i = 0b
here is a medium 16-bit int : med_i    = 2f1e
here is a normal 32-bit int : norm_i   = 000007c7
here is a big    64-bit int : big_i    = ffffffff3e9051b2
addr of little_i is ffffffff7ffff56b and the size is 1
addr of med_i    is ffffffff7ffff568 and the size is 2
addr of norm_i   is ffffffff7ffff564 and the size is 4
addr of big_i    is ffffffff7ffff558 and the size is 8

--------------------------------------------------
 size of the pointer little_p is 8
 the address of the pointer itself is ffffffff7ffff550


the pointer little_p now has the addr ffffffff7ffff558
The data there, in memory, at the addr is 0xffh
                             at addr+1 is 0xffh
                             at addr+2 is 0xffh
                             at addr+3 is 0xffh
                             at addr+4 is 0x3eh
                             at addr+5 is 0x90h
                             at addr+6 is 0x51h
                             at addr+7 is 0xb2h
```

All seems well here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the data at the address is `0xff`, so it has `1` in the sign bit. This means that the data is sign-extended on conversion to `int`, which takes place when the value is passed to `printf`. Sign-extending means filling the missing bytes of an `int` with the sign bit of the original value. In this case, this means filling the rest of the bits with ones, producing a string of `F`s ([demo 1](http://ideone.com/08IJ9c)).

Changing the format to `%hhx` will fix the problem ([demo 2](http://ideone.com/HSG6Cf); thanks, [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)!).

Comment: I just caught that myself.  Must remember to make that first coffee in the morning and then think before I post .. however this may be a reasonable lesson to me. Memory isn't signed data.  Its just memory.

Comment: also .. love your user name.  Yep, I remember when we had big computer control rooms and lots of das blinken lights :-)

Comment: @paullanken: Note also that the format for printing a char-sized quantity in hex is `%hhx`, not `%xh`. Changing the format would also produce the expected output, regardless of the signed-ness.

Comment: @MartinR: interesting. I have never used that. I just checked the man page for printf(3C) and sure enough there is something there for hh. I always assumed that a single byte could be printed in hex with %02x.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for a great comment - I edited the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast to (uint8_t*), your byte has value of 0xff which is -1 in decadic and it will be sign extended to 32 bits so it ends up as 0xffffffffh (again -1 in two's complement notation). So use unsigned types for unsigned data.